# When do I fight my first dragon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to fight a dragon, regardless of whether I win or lose, I just wanna do it to have fun! So where can I find some dragons?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just continue on the main quest. Your first dragon comes just after you reach Whiterun and complete the [Bleak Falls Barrow](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bleak_Falls_Barrow_%28quest%29) quest by bringing Farengar the Dragonstone. You'll speak to Jarl Balgruuf at Dragonsreach and then embark on a quest ("[Dragon Rising](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Rising)") with his right hand lady to kick some dragon ass. It's actually pretty low level too so you should be able to handle it. You'll also receive your first *shout*.

Comment: I killed the first dragon in level 3 or 4 so it's fairly early you will fight your first dragon.